# Why is Ubuntu capturing space after uninstallation?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

I had installed ubuntu 12.04 on Windows 7 through wubi. However, due to some issues I decided to uninstall that. During uninstallation I messed up things badly. I first deleted the 'Ubuntu' folder in C drive. Then I did uninstall ubuntu from control panel. Something went really wrong because after that I see that the 15 GB space, which was allocated to Ubuntu, is not freed yet. If I reboot the machine and select 'Ubuntu' then it does not reboot and shows an error that 'some files are not found' (pretty obvious). I am working on windows currently, but my 15 GB memory is captured due to improper uninstallation.

I know there are some pro-users of ubuntu. If anyone of you have any idea what could be the possible solution, kindly share that. Thanks in advance.

-Pavel

Comment: Did you delete c:\wubildr*?

Comment: Your problem is on the windows side of things of which we know nothing ... Maybe clear out trash?

Comment: The 15GB are allocated in folder ubuntu, especially \ubuntu\disks\root.disk. If you remove the folder ubuntu, "Ubuntu" doesn't allocate the 15 GB anymore. Maybe, Windows doesn't free the space immediately. Your Windows trash is empty ?

Answer (score 0):

You should consult the Wubi documentation on [manually uninstalling Wubi here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_manually_uninstall_Wubi.3F)

It explains how to remove all files and registry entries.